# Can't get user from Cognito with Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a user pool on AWS. I created a policy to access the userId information:

```json
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "cognito-idp:AdminGetUser",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:userpool/SOME_ID"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I associated the policy to the user used by the java spring-boot application (user/ZZZZZ). In Java I created the following function to retrieve some data from the user:

```java
    private User decodeFromCognito(String userId){
        BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY);
        AWSCognitoIdentityProvider client = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).build();
        AdminGetUserRequest adminGetUserRequest = new AdminGetUserRequest()
                .withUserPoolId( POOL_ID )
                .withUsername( userId );
        AdminGetUserResult adminGetUserResult = client.adminGetUser(adminGetUserRequest);
        User finalUser = new User();
        finalUser.setUserId( userId );
        for( AttributeType attribute : adminGetUserResult.getUserAttributes() ){
            switch ( attribute.getName() ){
                case "XXXXX" :
                    finalUser.setXXXXX( attribute.getValue() );
                case "YYYYY" :
                    finalUser.setYYYYY( attribute.getValue() );
            }
        }
        return finalUser;
    }
```

But when I run the code I keep getting this error message:

```
user/ZZZZZ is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:AdminGetUser on resource: arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:userpool/SOME_ID
```

Could anyone tell me what I am missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Check if there is any policy attached to the user where there is an [explicit Deny](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html) for the action. Check if there is any [permission boundary](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html) associated with the user. Check any [SCP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html) blocking access.

Comment: Use the [policy simulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html) to diagnose the issue

Answer (score 0):

To run this code, give the IAM user associated with your creds that you are using this policy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to everyone, I apologize to you all. The problem wasn't there, it was related to a missing character that was messing with my Spring Boot Configuration. Nevertheless, thanks to this post I learned about the policy simulator and the permission boundary, so thanks!